# Qt 5.4.0 install failing on libGL.so.1, but libgl-dev and ibglu-dev already installed

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, ubuntu, qt5

I am trying to install (offline installer) Qt 5.4.0 on linux 14.04 "Trusty Tahr" and I keep getting the error message:

*Warning: /home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

I've googled and searched and the answer seems to be to install **libgl-dev** and **libglu-dev**  but they are already installed, per the console messages I see when installing each:

### **libgl-dev**

```
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgl1-mesa-dev' instead of 'libgl-dev'
libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 598 not upgraded.`
```

### **libglu-dev**

```
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libglu1-mesa-dev' instead of 'libglu1-mesa-dev' 
libglu1-mesa-dev is already the newest version.
libglu1-mesa-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 598 not upgraded.`
```

So I see 2 possible problems but don't know how to adress either.

1. 'libglu1-mesa-dev' is being substituted for 'libglu1-mesa-dev'
2. libglu1-mesa-dev set to manually installed

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: Perhaps it is better suited for  AskUbuntu?

Comment: The problem is that my QT5.4.0 install is failing due to the described  error and I want to install QT5.4.0

Comment: Cannot you install it from PPA? Also, well, we cannot be sure how you got the console messages as you have not actually shown the commands that triggered those...

Comment: @JohnBerger: isn't Ubuntu supposed to hide such low-level details from you?

Comment: Sorry,here are the commands:  $ ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.4.0.run  and   

sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev   and   $ sudo apt-get install libgl-dev

Comment: @user3577369: are you joking or is it serious that you are trying to install libqt*4*-dev for Qt 5?

Comment: So is libGL.so.1 really exists in system?

Comment: @user3577369: do you have `libGL.so.1`? `find /usr/lib* -name libGL.so.1`. Also, just in case, you are not mixing 32 bit with 64 bit, right? Either way, `apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev` should work.

Comment: As I remember it have to be some Mesa package, not -dev

Comment: @folibis: I think you probably mean `libgl1-mesa-dri` for sparing a few megs. user3577369: you can always go dirty and do some `ln -s /usr/lib/something /usr/lib/libGL.so.1` alike hack for experimenting. :P

Comment: libGL.so.1  does exist

Comment: "libqt*4*-dev for Qt 5 "  there is no libqt5-dev.  i tried installing this because of another stackoverflow posting   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355837/installing-qt-on-linux-cannot-find-lgl

Comment: i've been trying to install the 64 bit version of qt5.4.0.  should I just erase that directory and try instaling the 32bit version?.

Comment: @folibis I found libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty  installed and am still getting the same error.  The error I posted was from the console.  The error displayed by the QT5.4.0 installer reads 'Error during installation process (qt.54.gcc_64):
Execution failed(Unexpected exit code: 127): "/home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool addQt --id qt.54.gcc_64 --name Qt %{Qt:Version} GCC 64bit --type Qt4ProjectManager.QtVersion.Desktop --qmake /home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake"`

Comment: I do not follow. If the library does exist, why cannot it find it? Have you tried to run the suggested `sudo ldconfig` just in case?

Comment: @Ipapp Here's what I get when i run `sudo ldconfig`  `/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide/libshiboken-python2.7.so.1.2 is not a symbolic link`  

`/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2 is not a symbolic link`

Comment: Might the problem be that the installer is expecting `libGL.so.1` in a different directory than where it is:   `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1`

Comment: Like I wrote above, please try `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1`. This would probably be even better: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ /home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool

Comment: if you are sure that libGL.so.1 exists try `ldd -d /path/to/libGL.so.1` to check all its dependencies.

Comment: @Ipapp I ran the ln -s command and the installer competed.  Upon finish, it tries to startr QTCreator , but the console shows this error `Could not initialize GLX`

Comment: @user3577369: remove the symlink, and try the LD_LIBRARY_PATH command, please.

Comment: Can you show the output of `file /home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool` and `uname -m`?

Comment: @Ipapp after removing the sym link, but prior to running the LD_LIBRARY_PATH command   `bd-01@bd01-Aspire-E1-531:~/Downloads$ file /home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool
/home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=92d781342c0f241a3d41ef81f6feda5776adafe7, stripped
bd-01@bd01-Aspire-E1-531:~/Downloads$ uname -m
x86_64`

Comment: @Ipapp when I run the LD_LIBRARY_PATH command I get the response "No operation requested" and what looks like a man page.   This is what I ran: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ /home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool`

Comment: @user3577369: another question, is there no PPA package for this?

Comment: Also, can you run `ldd -r /home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool`?

Comment: This is the URL that you used for downloading, yeah? http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.4.0.run

Comment: Are you getting this in the GUI's output dialog: `Warning: /home/bd-01/Qt5.4.0//Tools/QtCreator/bin/sdktool: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`?

Comment: Also, why not use `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`? It should really fix it!

Comment: @Ipapp Yes on the download link.  I downladed from this site  http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#  selected offline installer, "Qt 5.4.0 for Linux 64-bit (542 MB)"  which took me to  http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.4.0.run

Comment: @Ipapp  libgl1-mesa-dev is already installed   When I try to execute qtcreator from console I do get the error you mentioned  "... No such file or directory"

Comment: Because the installer completed without error and because of the 'cannot find' error, I went back and reran the linking command and rec'd the error: `Could not initialize GLX`  here's the screen `$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1

$ qtcreator  Starting process:  "/usr/bin/cmake" "--help" 
Could not initialize GLX
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: The core dump referenced above produced a 'details' window saying I had a multitude of packages out of date.  I installed all of them (55) but am still getting the `Could not initialize GLX`  message followed by a core dump.

Comment: Looks like its working.  I rebooted after installing all those packages and its working now.  Thanks to Ipapp and folibis for all your help

Comment: How do I designate an answer  and close the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have the following items done proper:

- sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
- not mixing 32 and 64 bits
- you used the proper download URL
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 is available
- etc

... it seems that, as I suspected, your system was b0rked. When you are dealing with packages through the package manager, you need to ensure that the system is in a clean and proper, and not in a broken state.

Things, like `apt-get auto remove` run means that you system is fundamentally broken and you have to fix your system first before experimenting with packages on top of it.

Comment: How does one "ensure that the system is not in a broken state"

Comment: @user3577369: `Things, like apt-get auto remove...`